# Environment vars passing to Robot Framework executions within VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, robotframework

I am trying to write Robot Framework tests using Visual Studio Code. Everything seems promising otherwise, but I am not able to get environment variables passed to the test execution runs no matter what I try.

I have a Python library accessed from my test cases that looks up values in `os.environ`. I need to populate this somehow.

I have a launch.json configuration of type `robotframework-lsp` (Robot Framework Language Server), but at least the *env* parameter does nothing. Likewise having an `envFile` does nothing.

I'm a bit of a VSCode beginner and the earlier responses I have been able to google seem confusing.

Comment: How are you passing environment variables to the test cases?

Comment: It's pre-existing code I shouldn't mess with in that regard. It sets variables by calling into Python and then reading os.environ from there. But I get a KeyError obviously.

Comment: Starting to feel like this may actually be a VSCode python bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6986

Comment: like one of the comments by Kim, the python extension does something different on the first run in the terminal, does it work if you run it a second/third time